# Un script en Google Sheets no corre la automatización porque esta configurado en getActiveSheet ()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

Tengo este código que funciona bien en modo editor con la hoja cálculo abierta, pero no la automatización (usando activadores / triggers), Debe ser porque no está seleccionada la hoja. No pude aplicar las respuestas que vi anteriores. No soy desarrollador. Me pareció entender que el problema es ese.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:Inbox is:unread to:me subject:Solicitud de ";

function getEmails_(q) {
var emails = [];
var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
for (var i in threads) {
    var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in msgs) {
        emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '/')
        ]);
    }
}
return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length,   
array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
if (array2d) {
    appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
}
markArchivedAsRead ();
}

function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:Inbox is:unread to:me subject:Solicitud de ');
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
};
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "funciona bien en modo editor, pero no la automatización? ¿saveEmails es la función principal? ¿Cómo la llamas, usando el botón ejecutar del editor de scripts o un activador (trigger)?

Comment: me refiero a cuando lo ejecuto manualmente con la hoja aboerta. En el historial de ejecuciones las distingue asi las que se ejecutan de ese modo. Gracias por tu interés.

Comment: No de a que te refieres con función principal, pero es el objeto del script. Que se guarden los datos recogidos en una fila de la hoja. El resto de las funciones son para que eso ocurra,.la primera busca los mensajes no leídos, Y la última luego de saveEmails los marca como leídos, para que la proxima vez no se dupliquen al recoger los mismos.

Comment: No de a que te refieres con función principal, pero es el objeto del script. Que se guarden los datos recogidos en una fila de la hoja. El resto de las funciones son para que eso ocurra,.la primera busca los mensajes no leídos, Y la última luego de saveEmails los marca como leídos, para que la proxima vez no se dupliquen al recoger los mismos.

Comment: En este sitio el espacio para publicar respuesta es para responder a la pregunta (la publicación inicial del hilo) no a comentarios. Para responder a un comentario haz clic en el enlace "añade un comentario" de la publicación que corresponda. Usa un @ como prefijo al nombre del usuario que respondes para que este reciba una notificación. Más detalles en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65)

Comment: Algunos llamamos "función principal" a la función que se llama desde elemento de interfaz de usuario, ya sea un botón, menú personalizado, desde el botón ejecutar del editor de Google Apps Script, etc. para realizar como dices tu "el objeto del script".

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/84986)

Comment: Gracias @Ruben.

Answer (score 1):

getActiveSheet() require que haya una hoja de cálculo abierta. Si vas a ejecutar tu script sin tener una hoja abierta, entonces lo primero es "abrir" un archivo de hoja de cálculo y luego tomar una hoja

Para "abrir" (entre comillas porque sólo se abre del lado del servidor, no de forma visible al usuario) usa los una de los métodos siguientes de la clase SpreadsheetApp:

- open()
- openById()
- openByUrl()

Los detalles se describen en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Luego ya que cuentes con un objeto de la clase Spreadsheet, usa

- getSheetByName()

ó

- getSheets() y luego el índice correspondiente a la hoja.

Los detalles los puedes consultar en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

Comment: Hola @Rubén, gracias por la información. Finalmente lo conseguí. Reemplacé la función saveEmails() por function run(){ agregando las dos que me diste.

Comment: function run(){
  var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
  if (array2d) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("168FvUCvOzqTyR2vswH4ibhm60qQ7yXRzcrgWZf3Azak");
    Logger.log(ss.getName());
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FormData");
    if (sheet != null) {
    Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }     lo programe para que se ejecute una vez por minuto y cuando no encuentra emails da error, con el consecuente envío del mail notificandolos. Se puede evitar que lo tome como error?Gracias

Comment: @Hernan527 : Si mi respuesta te fué útil, considera aceptarla. Referencia [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/someone-answers).

Comment: En relación a la pregunta que haces en comentarios, por favor publica un nueva pregunta.